# React: Implement Login with BASIC Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, basic-authentication, fetch-api

I want to create a react web app containing a login. My backend is implemented with JAX-RS and BASIC authentication. Here is a snippet of the `web.xml` and a `Resource`.

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>api</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ROLE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ROLE</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Resource:

```java
@GET
@PermitAll
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<OnlineStackDto> getData() {
    return dataService.getData();
}
```

All Requests from react are bundled in one file, `request.js`. Here is the get function as an example.

```js
const user = 'username';
const pass = 'password';

export function get(url) {
    return fetch(url, 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Of course, hardcoding username and password is not how the app can be deployed later. The function is called like this:

```
import {get} from "./request";
import React from "react";

export default class DataComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        get('onlinestacks').then(data => this.setState({myData: data}));
    }
}
```

The login-logic is realized using `react-router` and [React 16.3 Context-API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Thus, I can access the username/password in every component using a `Consumer`. Here is an example of how the data is set and used. For a more complete example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49756074/7677308).

```
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        };

        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    login(username, password) {
        this.setState({
            user: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                <Header/>
                /*Other Components*/
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }

}

export default class Header extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (<header>
            <UserContext.Consumer>{value =>
                <div className="username">{value.username}</div>
            }
            </UserContext.Consumer>
        </header>);
    }
}
```

My question is:
How can I use username and password from the Context in my requests *without* having to pass them everytime I want to make a request?

Comment: I can't understand what kind of goal you want to achieve. You want to send some requests with username, and some without?

Comment: @degr I want to send all requests with username. But the username should not be hardcoded. Instead I want the user to enter his name and use that in all requests

Comment: You need help with variable assignment? You don't know how to get value from text input and set it into variable?

Comment: @degr I have the necessary information (username, password) inside the `UserContext`. I can access it as shown in the `Header` component. I don't know how to use this data in the `request.js` file. Just setting it as a global variable feels wrong and the only other way I could think of, is to pass the user as a parameter to the request, like `function get(url, user)`. But this would make it necessary to implement a `UserContext.Consumer` in *every* component which needs to fetch data. This feels unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Can you give an example where you call `request` method? The proposed solution would depend on that. There are many ways to do it and each has its own drawbacks.

Comment: @MotiKorets There is a `DataComponent` in the question, giving an example for a `get` request

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions to this. You can use `bind` method and pass a bound `get` method with username and password set. So you get function will accept `username` and `password` as parameters

```
export function get(username, password, url)
```

And you Context.Provider will pass bound function

```
<UserContext.Provider value={get.bind(null,this.state.user,this.state.password)}>
```

To not trigger reflows you can lift the binding

```
login(username, password){
  this.setState({
        authenticatedGet: get.bind(null,username,password)
  });
}
//....
<UserContext.Provider value={this.state.authenticatedGet}>
```

I really don't think that you should use Context for this kind of stuff though. The thing is Context is good for UI logic and this is more about service layer. There are many other  solutions including passing `get` as prop where appropriate, or if you use `redux` with `redux-thunk` pass it as `thunk.withExtraArgument` but this is really out of scope  for your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Thinking about it, I came to the conclusion that you are right, and `Context` should not be used for that. Now, I'll implement a solution with cookies.